# How to call coordinates of "beacon" from c# code to .aspx code to show it in mouseover-tooltip when website is viewed in browser?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, web-applications

There is a big hall with machines inside. Near those machines, there are toolboxes, gear, etc. "beacons" which are tracked. All of this is displayed in a web app.
The c# code seems to know what coordinates those beacons have.
What I would like to accomplish is that these coordinates are displayed in the tooltip when you hover over the tooltip.

ASP.NET

```
<asp:Panel ID="DivBeacon" class=beacon runat="server" style="position:absolute;left:100px;top:100px;" >
    <span class="tooltip" data-tooltip="attr"></span>
    <div class="beacon-caption" >
        <asp:Literal runat="server"  id="LitBeacon" EnableViewState="false" >Beacon</asp:Literal>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

C#

```
private void ShowBeacon()
    {
        TableRow[] tableRowsBeacon = new TableRow[]
        {
            new TableRow(), 
            new TableRow(), 
        };

        string x= Beacon.Properties.FirstOrDefault(p => (p.Name == "posx")).Value;
        string y= Beacon.Properties.FirstOrDefault(p => (p.Name == "posy")).Value;
        this.DivBeacon.Attributes.CssStyle["left"] = x+"px";
        this.DivBeacon.Attributes.CssStyle["top"] = y+"px";

        if ((this.Beacon != null) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Beacon.Name))
        {
            LitBeacon.Text = Beacon.Name + string.Format("<br/>{0:0.##}","(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
        }
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to write it syntactically right, as the asp.net part refuses to show anything different than just text in between the "..." after "data-tooltip".

EDIT: I don't know how to clarify this more besides posting the whole code, which is quite long and I am pretty sure I am not allowed to.

The pure .css tooltip 
.css

```
.tooltip {
color: lightsteelblue;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: help;}

[data-tooltip] {
position: relative;}

[data-tooltip]::after {
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 3.5em;
    left: -0.75em;
    width: 5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    z-index: 100;
    color: #000;
    background-color: lightsteelblue;
    border: solid 1.5px black;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
}
```

is working, if you put some static text in it, but I can't find a way to link this to c# code.

I just have put the coordinates into the description text of beacon, it shows them there but that produces another problem: it shows too many decimals, I want just 2, but I can not use Math functions since although the coordinates are numbers it is getting them as string values from the server.

What I need is a working tooltip with coordinates in it or coordinates showing in the description of beacon

```
enter code here
```

Comment: do the data attributes on your button work?  if so you can use them to make a pure css tooltip

Comment: this is actually the problem, they do not work. the tooltip is pure css. How do I link that data attributes correctly, I didn't find anything good about this on the internet.

Comment: then you need to show us your rendered html and the css that you are using for your tooltip in a [mcve].  Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53377089/edit) your question and use the snippet button to add your code

Comment: Or follow this guide - it's pretty comprehensive: https://webdesignerhut.com/pure-css-tooltips-with-html5-data-attribute/